# ImageAdapter cannot be applied to fragment class

Tags: java, android

I've followed the documentation on how to use GridView and had the same issue as this guy [ImageAdapter cannot be applied to a Fragment Class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35488565/imageadapter-cannot-be-applied-to-a-fragment-class)

The code in my Fragment Class is as follows

```
public class SecondFragment extends Fragment {

    View myView;
    GridView gridview;

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        myView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.second_layout, container, false);
        gridview = (GridView) myView.findViewById(R.id.gridview);
        gridview.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(getActivity()));
        return myView;
    }
}
```

However I'm getting an error in the second to last line "Image Adapter cannot be applied to android.app.activity"

My ImageAdapter is as follows

```
public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    private Context mcontext;

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mthumbids.length;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ImageView imageView;
        if (convertView == null) {
            imageView = new ImageView(mcontext);
            imageView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(85, 85));
            imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
            imageView.setPadding(8, 8, 8, 8);
        }
        else  {
            imageView = (ImageView)convertView;
        }

        return imageView;
    }

    private Integer[] mthumbids =
            {
              R.drawable.img1, R.drawable.img2,
              R.drawable.img3, R.drawable.img4,
              R.drawable.img5, R.drawable.img6
            };
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to have a constructor in your `ImageAdapter` class which will take the context as a parameter.

And you have to set the background of the image based on the adapter position as well.

Here's the modified adapter class.

```
public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    private Context mcontext;

    public ImageAdapter (Context context) {
        mContext = context;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mthumbids.length;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ImageView imageView;
        if (convertView == null) {
            imageView = new ImageView(mcontext);
            imageView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(85, 85));
            imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
            imageView.setPadding(8, 8, 8, 8);

            // Add the following to load the image
            imageView.setBackground(ContextCompat.getDrawable(context, mthumbids[position]));
        }
        else  {
            imageView = (ImageView)convertView;
        }

        return imageView;
    }

    private Integer[] mthumbids =
            {
              R.drawable.img1, R.drawable.img2,
              R.drawable.img3, R.drawable.img4,
              R.drawable.img5, R.drawable.img6
            };
}
```

Comment: Thank you, however adding the line of code you suggested I get another error; setBackground in View cannot be applied to java.lang.integer

Comment: Had to change "context" to "mContext", but it works now, thank you so much

Comment: Glad to know that helped!

Answer (score 0):

Add this code in ImageAdapter class.

```
public ImageAdapter (Context context) {
    super();
    mContext = context;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, your code removed the error however when I run the app in the emulator my second fragment just appear blank and doesn't show the grid view

Comment: add super(); on constructor.

Answer (score 0):

You can also get the context from the parent in `getView()`. Then you don't have to pass and store the context. So your `getView` looks like this:

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ImageView imageView;
    if (convertView == null) {
        Context context = parent.getContext(); // <-- add this line
        imageView = new ImageView(context); // use the context from the parent
        imageView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(85, 85));
        imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
        imageView.setPadding(8, 8, 8, 8);
    }
    else  {
        imageView = (ImageView)convertView;
    }

    return imageView;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Missing constructor with argument context for ImageAdapter.
Only empty constructor will be created automatically
you should write constructors with specific argument values.

```
public ImageAdapter(Context context){
```

mContext = context;
}