# How do I place my image adapter (it is an infinite cycler view) in a fragment?

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I'm setting up an image adapter in my fragments. I recently learn the usefulness of Fragments and Therefore I am trying to switch from the traditional activities to a central activity with multiple fragments. But I cant get to display my images' infinite cycler view.

I have tried reading answers from previous questions here on Stack overflow ([ImageAdapter cannot be applied to fragment class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49904149/imageadapter-cannot-be-applied-to-fragment-class?rq=1) and [ImageAdapter cannot be applied to a Fragment Class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35488565/imageadapter-cannot-be-applied-to-a-fragment-class?noredirect=1&lq=1)) but I didnt really understand anything perhaps because I am a beginner in android studio with no educational background in coding. I have also tried youtube and everywhere.

I havent found tutorials to do this, I understand that fragments is relatively new in android studio

This is the fragment I am trying to switch to

```
    public TrendingFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    private static final String TAG = "Trending";


    HorizontalInfiniteCycleViewPager viewPager;
    List<TrendingHolder> TrendingList = new ArrayList<>();


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragme
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_trending, container, false);


        initData();
        viewPager = view.findViewById(R.id.view_pager);
        viewPager.setAdapter(new TrendingAdapter(getActivity()));


        return view;

    }


    private void initData() {
        //Adding the Images on board
        TrendingList.add(new TrendingHolder(R.drawable.ad_test));
        TrendingList.add(new TrendingHolder(R.drawable.burger_test));
        TrendingList.add(new TrendingHolder(R.drawable.italian_test));
        TrendingList.add(new TrendingHolder(R.drawable.pizza_test));
    }

}
```

This is my adapter class

```
public class TrendingAdapter extends PagerAdapter {

    Context context;
    List<TrendingHolder> TrendingList;
    private static final String TAG = "TrendingAdapter";

    public TrendingAdapter(Context context, List<TrendingHolder> trendingList) {
        this.context = context;
        this.TrendingList = trendingList;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return TrendingList.size();

    }

    @Override
    public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, @NonNull Object o){
        return view.equals(o);
    }

    @Override
    public void destroyItem(@NonNull ViewGroup container, int position, @NonNull Object object) {
        container.removeView((View)object);
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public Object instantiateItem(@NonNull ViewGroup container, int position) {
        //Inflate View
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.card_item, container, false);
        //View
        ImageView trending_image = (ImageView)view.findViewById(R.id.trending_holder);

        //Set Data
        trending_image.setImageResource(TrendingList.get(position).getImage());

        //set On Event Click
        view.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                //shop activity comes here
                Log.d(TAG, "onClick: added to Cart");
            }
        });

        container.addView(view);
        return view;

    }
}
```

This is my model for the images

```
public class TrendingHolder {
    private int image;

    public TrendingHolder(){

    }

    public TrendingHolder(int image) {
        this.image = image;
    }

    public int getImage() {
        return image;
    }

    public void setImage(int image) {
        this.image = image;
    }
}
```

I am getting this error TrendingAdapter( ) 
in TrendingAdapter cannot be applied
to
(androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity) in my Trending Fragment

Answer (score 0):

It seems like missing constructor parameter. The constructor of `TrendingAdapter` accepts 2  parameters `public TrendingAdapter(Context context, List<TrendingHolder> trendingList)`. But you pass 1 parameter `viewPager.setAdapter(new TrendingAdapter(getActivity()));`.